# why binlog doesn't log the DML statement?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, mysqlbinlog

two method compared
1. use test; create table t (a int);
2. create table test.t1(a int);

my result is the first one can log the binlog but the second one can't not

```
use test;create table t(a int);

mysqlbinlog -v mysql-bin.000005|grep create
use `test`/*!*/;
SET TIMESTAMP=1490090893/*!*/;
create table t(a int)
/*!*/;
DELIMITER ;
```

but when I do not use "use", DML cannot log in binlog,can tell me why?

```
create table test.t(a int);

mysqlbinlog -v mysql-bin.000005|grep create test.t
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you use statement based or row based logging? If it is statement based then you most likely have `binlog-do-db` set in your replication filters e.g. `binlog-do-db=test` so that only queries where the `default` database is `test` are written to your binary log.

e.g.

```
USE test;
CREATE table t . . .

USE test;
CREATE table otherdb.table . . .
```

both appear in your binary logs, but

```
USE otherdb;
CREATE table t2. . .

USE otherdb;
CREATE table test.t . . .
```

Don't appear.

In the first instance your default database is `test`, in the second it is `otherdb`.

see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-rules-db-options.html

Comment: hi，I have no binlog-do-db=test  item, and I test  row basement and statement statement, both of them need to add "use test" while data log in binary, is differenet from mysql document ~~ strange ! and mysql version is 5.5.9